# Куда выкладывать картинки для github и стоит ли создавать для этого репозиторий?

Tags: github, изображения

Нужно вставить картинки в проект. Загрузил картинки на яндекс диск, так там ссылка на картинку меняется. На фото-хостлинги как-то страшновато. Вдруг со временем удалят.
Вот думаю об отдельном репозитории на github для картинок.

---

Стоит ли так делать и, что вы считаете об этом?

Comment: А где вы храните код самого проекта?

Comment: В репозитории проекта. Где же ещё? Репозиторий на гитхабе

Answer (score 0):

Можно хранить в assets . В репозитории создаете страничку wiki или issue. В неё мышкой кидаете файл. В тексте появится ссылка - её можно использовать и в других местах. В readme.md, например.